# Rsync command not working with python

Tags: python, rsync

I am trying implement rsync with python. Here's my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

url = raw_input("Paste your URL:")
username = raw_input("Enter username:")
#password = raw_input("Enter password:")

source = username + "@" + url
#print source

print os.system('rsync -zvr --progress source /home/zurelsoft/R')
```

The logic is simple: user inputs the url and username stored in source with proper formatting. The source variable is then used in rsync command. I am inputting the valid URL and username of my server but I am getting this error:

```
rsync: link_stat "/home/name/source" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a static string.  Regardless of what the user inputs, you're always giving rsync the exact same commandline options.  You probably want `source` to be replaced with the value:

```
print os.system('rsync -zvr --progress {source} /home/zurelsoft/R'.format(source=source))
```

---

As a side note, this can be done better with `subprocess` :

```
subprocess.call(['rsync','-zvr','--progress',source,'/home/zurelsoft/R'])
```

It might not matter, but you'll close a *HUGE* security hole in your program this way (consider if the user put `; rm -rf ~;` as their username ...) and it's always a good idea practice good programming habits.

Answer (score 0):

Use subprocess.call

```
subprocess.call(["rsync", "-avz", "--exclude-from", "/tmp/exclude-list.txt", source, destination])
```

or if you need out put,

```
 output = subprocess.Popen(["rsync", "-avz", "--exclude-from", "/tmp/exclude-list.txt", source, destination])
```